# How can I get back my "Switch User" button?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, user-switching

I have a Microsoft wireless keyboard.  Under XP, the "key" key brings up the option to switch user.

Under Windows 7 Home, the same key automatically logs me out.  I've installed the drivers for Win7, and there's no option for switch user.

Note that this is on exactly the same hardware - dual boot Win7 and XP.

Is there any way to get this key (or any of the other keys, actually) to allow me to switch user?

Answer (score 2):

The switch user option may not appear if there is not another configured user account. Or if all the other user accounts are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Win key + L brings up the switch user screen. (It locks the desktop but allows you to switch user)